# Error: "Additional property mysql is not allowed" when setting up local WordPress environment

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

When attempting to set up a local WordPress development environment using Docker, I encountered an error message stating that:

> (root) Additional property MySQL is not allowed

The error occurred when I ran the command `docker compose up -d` with the following Docker Compose file:

```yaml
    web:
     image: wordpress
     links:
      - mysql
     environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=password
     ports:
      - "127.0.0.3:8080:80"
    mysql:
     image: mysql:5.7
     environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=my-wpdb
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've found a very very old example using the "version 1" Compose format.  For a long time, the Docker Compose tool interpreted files without a `version:` line as being in this format, but more recently the tool has changed to interpret these lines as being in a much newer, and somewhat incompatible, "Compose Specification" format.

I'd recommend using either [version 2](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/) or [version 3](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/) of the Compose file format (version 2 has some resource-constraint options for non-Swarm hosts that are often useful).  In spite of the Docker documentation claiming they're "legacy", every version of Compose from the past several years supports these.

For the file you show, the required changes are straightforward:

1. Indent the entire file one step, and add an unindented `services:` line above the existing content.
2. Above that, add another line `version: '3.8'` (or `'2.4'`).
3. Delete the obsolete `links:` block; Compose [provides network setup](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) for you so this isn't required.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    image: wordpress
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.3:8080:80"
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=my-wpdb
```

The newer file format has support for declaring named volumes in the Compose file itself, which would let you declare storage for the database, and [@ioeshu's extended example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74216672) includes the relevant `volumes:` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

This yaml code works fine

```
    services:
  db:
    # We use a mariadb image which supports both amd64 & arm64 architecture
    image: mariadb:10.6.4-focal
    # If you really want to use MySQL, uncomment the following line
    #image: mysql:8.0.27
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=somewordpress
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
      - MYSQL_USER=wordpress
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=wordpress
    expose:
      - 3306
      - 33060
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
      - wp_data:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 80:80
    restart: always
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=wordpress
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=wordpress
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress
volumes:
  db_data:
  wp_data:
```

Comment: no, it does not!